# Hyperic HQ 4.6.6 server is configured to run on wrong domain name

Tags: linux, ip, host, hyperic

After successfull installation of Hyperic on Linux I receive an information message with the following:

> Once the HQ server reports that it has successfully started, you can log in to your HQ server at: 
>   http://<***some-domain-name***>:7080/
>   username:hqadmin
>   password:hqadmin

Problem is that I can't access Hyperic via real IP. Also it is not possible to access it with ***some-domain-name*** as it is not really configured to be reached through remote machine (I guess that ***some-domain-name*** is taken from some settings in Linux during Hyperic installation).

So, my question: is it possible somehow to configure Hyperic to be accessed with the IP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appeared, Hyperic HQ server should be started under non-root user (eg - hyperic) like this:

> sudo -u hyperic ./hq-server.sh start

Hyperic HQ could be reached at http://<***some-domain-name***>:7080/ after that.
So, domain name instead of IP was not a real issue in that case.